# Query Number of Columns allowed

Tags: sql

All the query questions deal with a limited number of columns that are being "select"ed. I would like to chose a large number of columns. How many may be selected and is there a way to enter a range of columns instead of each individually.

Comment: If you want them all, there is `select * from [table_name]`

Comment: depdning on which database you are using, you can query the system tables to create a field list...saves typing

Comment: Agreed with previous comment. Let us know if you need help going that road.

Comment: You'll have to tell more about enter a range of columns, but another example is `select table_b.* from table_a join table_b on...`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your RDBMS. In MS SQL Server the limit is 4,096 columns per select.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx